# Using jar to generate file using php script

Tags: java, php, jvm

My jar program generate a parsed .srt file, I tried to use:

```
exec("/opt/lampp/htdocs/slim_app/src/uploads/java SubPars.jar file1", $output);
```

I want to generate a parsed file then uploaded it to the site is that possible?

Update: 
I added 2>&1 to show the errors, now I got:
/opt/lampp/htdocs/slim_app/src/public/../uploads/: Permission denied

I tried to give the file permission 755 but it doesn't work. What should I do !?

Comment: Do you have Java installed in `/opt/lampp/htdocs/`???

Comment: I can run java file from .../uploads/java using command line normally.
I don't understand why I need to install java in htdocs?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read more about the permissions but almost nothing new to help me for solving my problem.
So I tried another function that requires permissions, when I execute this command:

```
$output = shell_exec("less ./../uploads/java/file1.srt");
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

everything goes well.!

Now I am using shell_exec(); to execute my jar files but I don't know what is the problem with exec(); in particular even when that I checked it and it's enabled. !

This is an example that could help someone in the future:

```
$output = shell_exec("java -jar ./../uploads/java/SubPars.jar ./../uploads/java/file1.srt ar");
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
exec("java /opt/lampp/htdocs/slim_app/src/uploads/SubPars.jar file1", $output);
```